# Is there a way to customise for multiple Facebook share buttons?

Tags: facebook, share

I had research a lot but I still find no possible ways. is there a way to customise for example 10 different Facebook share buttons on one page. each button will have different custom image, custom text, custom link? I do not want to use any app ID.

Currently Facebook sharer.php depreceated the use of inline custom text. Is there any other ways to do it?

please help.

Thanks.

Comment: What language/framework are you using? Please be more specific and add appropriate tags.

Comment: @user502144 hi, I'm using normal html Css Javascript. Do you know BuzzFeed quiz? At the end of a quiz, they allow to share results. those results will have different visuals. So I was wondering how to share every different results accordingly using custom html/Javascript if there is any

Comment: You can use different URLs, as @luschn suggested – but be aware, that Facebook will count likes and shares for each of those separately then. Your other alternative is to use the Feed dialog – that still allows to specify those values at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

You only need to use a separate URL for each Share Button, each separate URL needs to have their own Open Graph tags (og:title, og:description, og:image, ...). For example:

- https://yourdomain.com/?shareId=1
- https://yourdomain.com/?shareId=2

Different URL, different OG tags possible.